# JavaScript validation file not working: "ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined" (html linked)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, referenceerror

(edit: code updated)

I am running into an error, when trying to clientside-validate with JavaScript that the user has filled in the forms correctly in the *Register* part of my HTML form.
The HTML and JS file are pretty straightforward:

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spwx1rfd/6/))

**JavaScript and HTML:**

```js
function validateForm() {
  var name  = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var email  = document.getElementById('email').value;
  
  if (name == null || name == "" || checkIfSpaceOnly(name) == false) {
   return false;
   }
  
  else if (email == null || email == "" || validateEmail(email) == false){
   return false;
   }
 
  else
   return true;
 }
 
  
 //other methods used in validateForm:
 function checkIfSpaceOnly(input) {
 var re = /\S/;
 return re.test(input);
 }

 function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
 }
 
  
  
 window.onload = function() 
  {
 var submitBtn  = document.getElementById('submit');
 submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validateForm);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">

</head>

<div class = "body1">
 <div class = "forms" id="forms">
 <h2>Log in</h2>
  <form name='loginform' action='login.php' method='POST'>
   <input type='email' name='email' placeholder="Email" ><br>
   <input type='password' name='password' placeholder="Password" ><br><br>
   <input type='submit' value='Log in'><br><br>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <br><h2>Register</h2>
  <form onsubmit="" name="register" action="register.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  
   <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username"><br>
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email"/><br>
   <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwoord"><br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create user">
   
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

So the problem is, it's like the JS file isn't used at all by the HTML file. The form gladly registers any user, no matter if they fulfill the JavaScript file's *if* conditions or not.

I checked the console, and it says (when the user has been registered), *"ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined"*.

Except checking that the file directories are correct of course, I have searched and read about both general HTML JS form validation Errors, 20-something "similar question" on here, and that specific ReferenceError. I've changed values, names, moved code parts around.... but I can't seem to find the problem and don't know what to do, although it feels like it's just a simple mistake somewhere in the code.

Comment: You have error in your code in line `if (uName == "") || checkIfSpaceOnly(uName) == false) {` it should be `if (uName == "" || checkIfSpaceOnly(uName) == false) {`

Comment: First thing I'd do is fix the javascript error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||`

Comment: Also, try writing your `validateForm` function before `window.onload`...

Comment: (As below commented) tried this, still didn't work :/  (although the code's a bit different now, check the question/code update if possible, thousand thanks!)

As it is now, the console doesn't even print a ReferenceError, the user is simply registered. :l

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 problems

1. Your fiddle is setup incorrectly; all the code is wrapped in an `onload` which means your `validateForm` method is not accessible from HTML markup
2. You have 2 `onsubmit` attributes in the form - the second contains what it should contain but is being ignored because of the first
3. You assign the event handler both in markup and in code. Choose one, stick with it.

---

When you fix these 3 problems, it works as expected and does not submit the form if anything goes wrong (ie, `false` is returned from `validateForm`)

https://jsfiddle.net/spwx1rfd/7/

Comment: This did fix it, thank you! I thought `onload` was required always, so there I learnt something, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the if condition, you have made a mistake.

Wrong code

```
if (uName == "") || checkIfSpaceOnly(uName) == false) {
    return false;
}
```

Right code

```
if (uName == "" || checkIfSpaceOnly(uName) == false) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, still didn't work :/  (although the code's a bit different, check the question/code update if possible, thousand thanks!)

As it is now, the console doesn't even print a ReferenceError, the user is simply registered.  :l